# FormControl / FormGroup / FormArray value type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want my `FormControl` (`FormGroup` / `FormArray`) be strongly typed so when I have e.g.

```
interface SomeSource {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

and I transformed it to e.g.

```
let form = new FormGroup<SomeSource>({
  id: new FormControl('test id'),
  name1: new FormControl('test name')
});
```

TypeScript had thrown an error: the `name` is not found on `FormGroup`.

Also in the ideal world the `form.value` should be of `SomeSource` type (and not `any`).

Problem is that there is no way to specify this generic type for any `AbstractFormControl` child.

I think this is fairly easy to override `FormGroup` with an own interface. However, is there a way to achieve this just using Angular? If no, are there third party solutions?

Motivation: I want to easily refactor my `SomeSource`. Currently when I refactor `SomeSource` interface, the form is not adapted and no error is thrown => there is a room for some bugs.

Comment: well you are using `name1` in your formgroup?

Comment: yes, because I want an error when I have a typo or I refactor my `SomeSource`. This is just a typo simulation

Comment: I don't think the Angular form classes provide this functionality, but I think you should be able to create your own TS class and leverage generics to achieve this behavior.  Reply back if you need an example.

Comment: @rrjohnson85 thanks, I think I can handle it. I just want to avoid reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v14, Angular implemented native typings for the Form module: https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: *Angular v14* finally added typed forms, see the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms).

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

There is an elegant solution for your problem - leverage TypeScript declaration files (`*.d.ts`) to introduce generic interfaces extending the standard form classes like `AbstractControl`, `FormControl`, etc. It doesn’t introduce any new functionality and has no footprint in the compiled JavaScript, but at the same time enforcing strong type checking.

It was [suggested](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13721#issuecomment-468745950) by Daniele Morosinotto in March this year and [there are talks](https://twitter.com/IgorMinar/status/1101527731018194944) now to include it in Angular 9.

Adopting the solution is straightforward:

1. Download `TypedForms.d.ts` from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dmorosinotto/76a9272b5c45af1f78a61e7894df5777) and save it as `src/typings.d.ts` in your project (Angular 6+ already knows how to use this file).
2. Start using the new types (`FormGroupTyped<T>`, `FormControlTyped<T>`, etc.) whenever you need a strong type validation (see examples in [that gist](https://gist.github.com/dmorosinotto/76a9272b5c45af1f78a61e7894df5777) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typedforms?file=index.ts)).

For more information, check out a [blog post](https://alex-klaus.com/stongly-typed-angular-forms/) analysing available solutions for strongly typed forms.